# Curve construction with Python's RATESLIB package

Tags: programming, interest-rates

As per the user guide of Python's RATESLIB package (https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i_guide.html#guide-doc), below example is provided to construct a Curve

```
from rateslib.curves import Curve

usd_curve = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2022, 1, 1): 1.0,
        dt(2022, 7, 1): 0.98,
        dt(2023, 1, 1): 0.95
    },
    calendar="nyc",
)
```

My question what is the type of the curve? Is it basically a `discount curve`? I dont seem to find any such definition in their User guide.

Comment: https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c_curves.html#curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a curve parametrised by discount factors. The initial node date must be 1.0.

Including the defaults that curve is actually the same as

```python
usd_curve = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2022, 1, 1): 1.0,
        dt(2022, 7, 1): 0.98,
        dt(2023, 1, 1): 0.95
    },
    calendar="nyc",
    interpolation="log_linear",
    modifier="MF",
    convention="ACT360",
)
usd_curve.plot("1b")
```

[image]

Comment: There is no "nyc" calendar, even if you.see one on a term aheet :) https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60330/quantlib-python-ql-schedule-getting-end-of-month-dates/60361#60361

Comment: Well it has to be called something. This "nyc" calendar's hols are listed here, and it is back tested against the prior publication dates of all the SOFR fixings. https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rateslib.calendars.get_calendar.html#id1

Comment: The new york bond calendar differs a little from the new york stock exchange calendar. Using the wrong new york calendar sometimes causes small differences. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57666/does-the-usgs-holiday-calendar-used-for-sofr-fixings-include-good-friday/57670#57670

Comment: Maybe it would be best to call this specific calendar referenced here the "sofr" calendar. Take your point. Sounds like a job in itself managing all these cals.

Comment: SOFR uses SIFMA calandar, in which, e.g., Good Friday is usually a holiday, but in a few rare cases just an early close. Yes, managing calendar data is complicated and not much fun, but at least referencing a right one would help - then d/l the dates feom Bbg CDR or a vendor like financialcalendar.com

Comment: Or tradinghours.com .